# How to add data to the array correctly

Tags: php

Help me how to add data to the array correctly.Below I give an example of what I want to get in the end after printing the array

```
$arr = [];

    $data = [
        "offer_id" => (string)777380,
        "price" => (string)5633
    ];
    
    array_push($arr, $data);


print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

I want to get this

```
    {
      "prices": [
        {
          "offer_id": "777380",
          "price": "5633"
        },
        {
          "offer_id": "777380",
          "price": "5633"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: `$arr['prices'] = [];` and `array_push($arr['prices'], $data);` and you are good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below:

```
    $arr['prices']=[];

    $data = [
        "offer_id" => (string)777380,
        "price" => (string)5633
    ];
    
    array_push($arr['prices'], $data);

    $data = [
      "offer_id" => (string)777380,
      "price" => (string)5633
  ];
  
  array_push($arr['prices'], $data);


print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [];

$data = [
    "offer_id" => (string)777380,
    "price" => (string)5633
];

$arr['prices'][] = $data;


print_r(json_encode($arr));
```